# Real Time Output Of Processed Inputs

Tags: c#, wpf, real-time

Being a beginner in C# I am having problem in a specific implementation. I need to compute two data in real time by which I mean ki the output shows as soon as the inputs are provided with no click of button necessary. 
 - For example I have a Text Box where if a type a number 5 gets added to it and the output shows in a Label. The label automatically updates when more numbers are typed in real time.

How do I achieve this?
Thanks !

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far, it will help us help you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of events?

Comment: @Chris I am not familiar with events except the few basic ones. I haven't written anything so far as I don't know the procedure, but given a waypoint I can surely write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before explaining the specifics, it's important to point out that from the code's perspective there isn't much difference between clicking a button or responding to the TextBox's event. Here's what I mean.

In addition to calling code procedurally from within your own methods like this:

```
void MyMethod(argument)
{
    ...Other Code...
    DoSomething(argument);
    ...Other Code...
}
```

.Net also allows you to attach method calls to [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). Events are just references to delegates(I'll leave it up to you to research delegates), but they allow you to asynchronously execute your code based on external interaction.

In your question you say that you want to perform a calculation without making the user click a button. Before going into how you'll accomplish that, lets think about what you'd do if there were a button. Chances are you'll drag & drop a button onto the designer surface, then double click it. Behind the scenes you'll suddenly have a method that looks something like this:

```
void button_ButonClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs args)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

So you'll go and populate the new method's body with your calculation logic. Under the hood you've actually just had the designer hook that new method up to the Button's click event. So in your case, whether you're adding the calculation logic to a button click or the `TextBox`'s TextChanged event, you're actually doing almost the same thing.

Just for reference, here's the MSDN documentation for TextBox's [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) .

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Pretty helpful ! I will try to write the code and post if I have further problems. We studied delegates a bit but never used it as it was beyond the reach of our OOP 101 course. At least now I know which direction to look at.

Answer (score 1):

OK I will give it a shot :)

Assume two textboxes and a label on a form.

Each textbox has a text_changed event handler, i.e. if you type something in either text box, the event handler code is called and there you can access the text of each textbox and transform the text into two numbers.

Then you compute the 2 numbers as per your rules and the result is displayed in the label.

This is a very simplified explanation! There must be validation of the inputs in the textboxes to ensure the data format is correct.

Ask more questions if this is not clear enough.